# Find the smallest integer n > 1 such that the product of the factors of n is $n^{15}$

Tags: factoring

Find the smallest integer n > 1 such that the product of the factors of n is $n^{15} $

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I don't even get how it's possible. The factors of the number n is n itself. It's basically asking to find n given: $n^{15}=n$

Comment: Hint: if $n=8$ then the factors of $n$ are $1,2,4,8$ and their product is $64$, which is $n^2$.  See if you can do something similar to get $n^{15}$ instead of $n^2$.

Comment: A generalization of David's hint: in general, if $\pi(n)$ denotes the product of the factors of $n$, then we can show

$$\pi(n) = n^{d(n)/2}$$

where $d(n)$ denotes the number of divisors of $n$ (sometimes denoted $\sigma_0(n)$).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there is a set of divisors of $n$ say $D_n = {d_1, d_2, d_3, ..., d_k}$.

Note that for each divisor $d \in D_n$, $\frac{n}{d} \in D_n$.

Hence $$\Pi_{d_i\in D_n}d_i= n^{k/2}$$

Thus you need to find $n$ which has $k=30$ factors. (Note that $k=31$ could also do the job but as @OscarLanzi says, we are looking for the smallest $n$, so we use the smaller value)

If $n = p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}...$ where $p_i$ is a prime, the number of divisors is $k = \Pi(k_1+1)(k_2+1)\dots$

Hence, $30 = 30 \cdot 1 = 15 \cdot 2 = 10 \cdot 3 = 6 \cdot 5 = 5 \cdot 3 \cdot 2$ can be represented as a set of powers of primes. Since we need the least, we can consider them to be powers of the lowest primes $2, 3, 5$

Among the following, the least is:
Some possible values of $n$ will hence be:

- $2^{29}$ corresponding to $k = 30 \cdot 1$
- $2^{14} \cdot 3^1$ corresponding to $k = 15 \cdot 2$
- $2^5 \cdot 3^4$  corresponding to $k = 6 \cdot 5$

The least of these seems to be $n = 720 = 2^4 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^1$ corresponding to $30 = 5 * 3 * 2$

Comment: Technically, $n$ could have $31$ divisors instead of $30$.  With an odd number of divisors their product is $n^{(k-1)/2}$ because we do not double count the square root which exists as a divisor in this case.  However, the smallest number with $31$ divisors is greater than $720$.

Comment: @Mirko fixed, thanks!

Comment: @OscarLanzi thanks, added a comment